# Produce this array from combining these 2 other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 arrays in node.js;

```
var alerts_arr =
[
    {
        "Name": "XXX", "symbol": "XXX.SI", "relationship": ">=", "price_alert": 3, "Remarks": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "YYY", "symbol": "YYY.SX", "relationship": ">=", "price_alert": 2.21, "Remarks": ""
    }
];

var results_arr =
    [
        {
            "symbol": "XXX", "name": "XXX.SI", "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z", "lastPriceOnly": 3.05
        }
        ,
        {
            "symbol": "YYY", "name": "YYY.SX", "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z", "lastPriceOnly": 2.2
        }
    ];
```

I want to combine these 2 arrays such that the result will look like this;

```
var combine_arr =
    [
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "symbol": "XXX.SI",
            "relationship": ">=",
            "price_alert": 3,
            "Remarks": "",
            "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z",
            "lastPriceOnly": 3.05
        },
        {
            "Name": "YYY",
            "symbol": "YYY.SX",
            "relationship": ">=",
            "price_alert": 2.21,
            "Remarks": "",
            "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z",
            "lastPriceOnly": 2.2
        }
    ]
;
```

How can this be done in node.js or javascript?

I tried `var finalObj = alerts_arr.concat(results_arr);` initially but the result was quite off.

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org). Those are simple objects.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - try JSON.parse on `var alerts_arr =[ ...` etc - and you'll see that is **NOT** JSON

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan JSON is the string represenation of an object, hence the acronym

Comment: @user768421 - have you tried anything yourself, or are you too busy editing JSON in and out of your question?

Comment: I tried `var finalObj = alerts_arr.concat(results_arr);`. But that is quite off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _ = require('lodash');


var alerts_arr =
[
{
    "Name": "XXX", "symbol": "XXX.SI", "relationship": ">=", "price_alert": 3, "Remarks": ""
},
{
    "Name": "YYY", "symbol": "YYY.SX", "relationship": ">=", "price_alert": 2.21, "Remarks": ""
}
];

var results_arr =
[
{
    "symbol": "XXX", "name": "XXX.SI", "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z", "lastPriceOnly": 3.05
}
,
{
    "symbol": "YYY", "name": "YYY.SX", "lastDate": "2015-11-05T16:00:00.000Z", "lastPriceOnly": 2.2
}
];


var transformed_arr = alerts_arr.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key === 'Name') {
      obj['symbol'] = item[key];
    } else if(key === 'symbol') {
      obj['name'] = item[key];
    } else { 
      obj[key] = item[key]; 
    }
  });
  return obj;
});

var result = _.merge(transformed_arr, results_arr);
```

1. transform the `alerts_arr` to match the results_arr,
2. then use `lodash` `merge` to merge two arrays

Comment: May I ask in what ways is `alerts_arr` transformed to match `results_arr`? Why do you need to match before merge?

Comment: because the `name` in results_arr is `symbol` in alters_arr, that's why I need to transform

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the values are unique and symbol<->name is the key, here's a quick sample (without error handling):

```
var combine_arr = [];

// Transform to associative array for faster fetching
var transformed_results = results_arr.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    previous[current.name] = current;
    return previous;
}, {});

for (var i = 0; i < alerts_arr.length; i++) {
    var alert = alerts_arr[i];

    combine_arr.push({
        Name: alert.Name,
        symbol: alert.symbol,
        relationship: alert.relationship,
        price_alert: alert.price_alert,
        Remarks: alert.Remarks,
        lastDate: transformed_results[alert.symbol].lastDate,
        lastPriceOnly: transformed_results[alert.symbol]. lastPriceOnly
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [lodash](https://lodash.com) to solve this in one line:

```
_.zipWith([ alerts_arr, results_arr ], _.merge)
```